# Book on Android App development using Ruby

Tags: android, ruby, mobile

I am a Ruby developer and has liking towards ROR. Now, I want to develop an Android/Smartphone App using Ruby language. How and where should I proceed. Are there any specific frameworks and book for same?

Answer (score 3):

While I personally have no experience with Ruby on Android, this sounds like an interesting topic so I looked it up. It seems like a good place to start would be the the [Ruboto wiki on github](https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto-core/wiki). There is even a [getting started](https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto-core/wiki/Tutorial%3a-Getting-started-with-Ruboto) entry.
Given that you're coming from rails, [this topic about ActiveRecord](https://github.com/ruboto/ruboto-core/wiki/Tutorial%3a-Using-an-SQLite-database-with-ActiveRecord) in Ruboto might be useful too.

Unfortunately, there do not seem to be any books dedicated to the topic yet. Any other book about Android development will still be useful, as it will be necessary to know the Android api.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is one fremework Called [RHO](http://rhomobile.com/products/rhodes/) which is used to build a cross platform mobile application. It is in ruby language.